# Do I have to manually create tables for SQLite in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, sqlite, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to switch from mariaDb to SQLite database in spring boot. I've been following some tutorials and after some time I finally got it to work but when I run the app I got following error:

```
[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: user)
```

My `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlite:IperfDataBase
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.sqlite.JDBC;
spring.jpa.database-platform=my.packages.database.SQLiteDialect
```

My DataSource `@Bean`:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
   DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
   dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
   dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:sqlite:IperfDataBase");
   return dataSourceBuilder.build();
}
```

MySQLiteDialect

```
package my.packages.database;

import java.sql.Types;

import org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunctionTemplate;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.VarArgsSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.type.StringType;

public class SQLiteDialect extends Dialect {
    public SQLiteDialect() {
        registerColumnType(Types.BIT, "integer");
        registerColumnType(Types.TINYINT, "tinyint");
        registerColumnType(Types.SMALLINT, "smallint");
        registerColumnType(Types.INTEGER, "integer");
        registerColumnType(Types.BIGINT, "bigint");
        registerColumnType(Types.FLOAT, "float");
        registerColumnType(Types.REAL, "real");
        registerColumnType(Types.DOUBLE, "double");
        registerColumnType(Types.NUMERIC, "numeric");
        registerColumnType(Types.DECIMAL, "decimal");
        registerColumnType(Types.CHAR, "char");
        registerColumnType(Types.VARCHAR, "varchar");
        registerColumnType(Types.LONGVARCHAR, "longvarchar");
        registerColumnType(Types.DATE, "date");
        registerColumnType(Types.TIME, "time");
        registerColumnType(Types.TIMESTAMP, "timestamp");
        registerColumnType(Types.BINARY, "blob");
        registerColumnType(Types.VARBINARY, "blob");
        registerColumnType(Types.LONGVARBINARY, "blob");
        // registerColumnType(Types.NULL, "null");
        registerColumnType(Types.BLOB, "blob");
        registerColumnType(Types.CLOB, "clob");
        registerColumnType(Types.BOOLEAN, "integer");

        registerFunction( "concat", new VarArgsSQLFunction(StringType.INSTANCE, "", "||", "") );
        registerFunction( "mod", new SQLFunctionTemplate( StringType.INSTANCE, "?1 % ?2" ) );
        registerFunction( "substr", new StandardSQLFunction("substr", StringType.INSTANCE) );
        registerFunction( "substring", new StandardSQLFunction( "substr", StringType.INSTANCE) );
    }

    public boolean supportsIdentityColumns() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean hasDataTypeInIdentityColumn() {
        return false;
    }
    public String getIdentityColumnString() {
        return "integer";
    }

    public String getIdentitySelectString() {
        return "select last_insert_rowid()";
    }

    public boolean supportsLimit() {
        return true;
    }

    protected String getLimitString(String query, boolean hasOffset) {
        return new StringBuffer(query.length()+20).
                append(query).
                append(hasOffset ? " limit ? offset ?" : " limit ?").
                toString();
    }

    public boolean supportsTemporaryTables() {
        return true;
    }

    public String getCreateTemporaryTableString() {
        return "create temporary table if not exists";
    }

    public boolean dropTemporaryTableAfterUse() {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean supportsCurrentTimestampSelection() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isCurrentTimestampSelectStringCallable() {
        return false;
    }

    public String getCurrentTimestampSelectString() {
        return "select current_timestamp";
    }

    public boolean supportsUnionAll() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean hasAlterTable() {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean dropConstraints() {
        return false;
    }

    public String getAddColumnString() {
        return "add column";
    }

    public String getForUpdateString() {
        return "";
    }

    public boolean supportsOuterJoinForUpdate() {
        return false;
    }

    public String getDropForeignKeyString() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No drop foreign key syntax supported by SQLiteDialect");
    }

    public String getAddForeignKeyConstraintString(String constraintName,
                                                   String[] foreignKey, String referencedTable, String[] primaryKey,
                                                   boolean referencesPrimaryKey) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No add foreign key syntax supported by SQLiteDialect");
    }

    public String getAddPrimaryKeyConstraintString(String constraintName) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No add primary key syntax supported by SQLiteDialect");
    }

    public boolean supportsIfExistsBeforeTableName() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean supportsCascadeDelete() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

User @Entity:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.*;

import static javax.persistence.FetchType.*;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.*;

@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @JsonIgnore
    private String username;
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
    private Port port;
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(fetch = EAGER)
    private Collection<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<Log> logs=new HashSet<>();
}
```

And my repo for It:

```
import UPCPolska.Iperf.data.archetypes.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Of course I have more tables with relations but It's to many to show here. Maybe my database is created incorrect, I just created an empty file with no extension, do I have to initialize it? Also do I need to do something special to use forgeing keys? What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create your tables automatically by just adding this config in to your `application.propertis`:

> ```
> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
> ```

it has update, create-drop and other options that you can read from the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html).

at the time you start your springboot application it will create your tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can create tables automatically by adding following property in to your application.properties:

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create